# ArrayList is null upon returning from another activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList of items that is going to be sent to another activity. The purpose of the ArrayList is to hold items like a shopping cart, and the delete activity shows the items in the user's shopping cart and allows them to delete items. Except on returning from the delete activity the ArrayList is empty.

Code for onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // instantiating layout features
    priceEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceEditText);
    addItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItemButton);
    gps = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.locationCheckBox);
    tax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taxEditText);
    subTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subTotalTextEdit);
    total = (Button) findViewById(R.id.totalitemsButton);
    totalTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalTextEdit);
    context = this;
    sTotal = 0.0;
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextField);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteItemButton);
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    // adding listeners
    addItem.setOnClickListener(click);
    total.setOnClickListener(done);
    delete.setOnClickListener(remove);
}
```

Code for starting new activity:

```
private OnClickListener remove = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                com.JPT3Productions.salestaxcalc.MainActivity.this,
                Delete.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("array", items);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Finally, receiving the intent:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    ArrayList<Item> items = (ArrayList<Item>) bundle.getSerializable("array");
    final TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl);
```

Comment: I believe you do not update your array list after deleting some elements. After retrieving the array list in interest in another class you operate in the class it is retrieved in there for in order to update the content you would need to call a set method to update the content. That is what I believe is going wrong.

Comment: do you think that I should make an ArrayList instance variable in my Items class and add methods to manipulate the ArrayList?

Comment: I believe so - that would be one way how to do it. However, from what you've described this array list should be a class variable and by that I mean it has to be 'static'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is possibly getting destroyed and recreated when the delete activity is shown.

You should implement the lifecycle events to save instance data, like the shopping cart, so it will be preserved if your activity is recreated.

Check the docs on [Saving and Restoring Activity State](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for information on how to do that.

Comment: Ill check it out! Do you think adding an ArrayList instance variable in my Items class would help at all?

Comment: You could but that would be a static, not instance, variable. In that case you can just make it a static variable in your activity. In general that's not a good practice because you could theoretically have multiple different instances of your activity on the back stack at any time. (Of course that is configurable too)

Comment: I'll tweak around with it and hopefully I can figure it out. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.